# SQLite sort varchar that contains letter and number

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a table where I have field traffic_num(`varchar`) that contains this data

```
A100
A586
A4594
A125
A2
A492
```

now I want to sort that data ascending order. It would be really easy if traffic_num contains only number (without letter `A`), then I could cast `varchar` to `integer` `CAST(traffic_num as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC`. But what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr` to first order by the first alphabet character and then by the number following it.

```
select * from tablename
order by substr(traffic_num,1,1), cast(substr(traffic_num,2) as signed integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is by sorting by the length and then the value:

```
order by length(traffic_num), traffic_num
```

This works when the values are integers.